# Check for [] simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, is-empty

However I try to test if `x` is `[]` I fail, seems that it should be trivial, but can't figure out how to do it.

if I run `x = rmi('get',subsystemPath);`

```
ans = []
```

I've tried

```
x == []
x
isempty(fieldnames(x))
isEmpty(x)
```

but nothing works

```
function requirements = GetRequirementsFromSubsystem(subsystemPath)
    x = rmi('get',subsystemPath);
    if(isempty(fieldnames(x)))          %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%<------
        requirements = 0;
    else
        requirements = {x.description}; % Fails if do this without a check
    end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x` is a `struct`, right? In that case, according to [this posting](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/296263) on the MATLAB newsgroup, there are two kinds of emptiness for structs:

1. `S = struct()` => no fields

   `isempty(S)` is FALSE, because `S` is a [1 x 1] struct without fields
2. `S = struct('Field1', {})` => fields, but no data

   `isempty(S)` is TRUE, because `S` is a [0 x 0] struct with fields

For me, `isempty(fieldnames(S))` works only for the first case in Octave, at least.

If `x` on the other hand, is an array, not a struct, then `isempty(x)` should work.

```
>> S = struct()
S =

  scalar structure containing the fields:


>> isempty(S)
ans = 0
>> isempty(fieldnames(S))
ans =  1
>> S = struct('Field1',{})
S =

  0x0 struct array containing the fields:

    Field1

>> isempty(S)
ans =  1
>> isempty(fieldnames(S))
ans = 0
>> x = []
x = [](0x0)
>> isempty(x)
ans =  1
```

Comment: Similar discussion at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/153192